# Bottle does not recognize Axios.js json post

Tags: javascript, python, cors, bottle, axios

I'm trying to make a post request with Axios to a backend coded in Python bottle.

The problem is that i'm getting a `500 internal` when the request is fired.

First, here is the Axios request code:

```
const data = {date: formatDate(date), titles}
post(`${API_URL}/save_day_titles`, data)
  .then(res => {
    console.log('response success', {...res});
  })
  .catch(res => {
    console.log('response', {...res});
  });
```

And the bottle code:

```
@planApi.route('/api/v3.6/save_day_titles', method=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def plan_save():
    date = request.json['date']
    titles = request.json['titles']
    plan = {
        'date': datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
        'titles': titles 
    }
    id = titlesMongo.insert_one(plan).inserted_id
    return {"id": str(id), "plan_date": date, "planification": titles}
```

The error logged in the web console is plain and simple:

> OPTIONS xxx/api/v3.6/save_day_titles 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load xxx/api/v3.6/save_day_titles. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

It looks like a CORS but i'm making a lot of other requests (get requests) and there is no CORS errors... anyway, when i try to log the body in the server like: `print request.body.parse()` the log is:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2017 18:18:45] “POST /api/v3.6/save_day_titles HTTP/1.0” 500 765
>   b’'

The weird thing is, with CURL the request is succesful:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{ "date": "2017-08-15", "titles": [{"title": "title test", "url":"xxx/xxx", "category": "category test"}] }' "xxx/api/v3.6/save_day_titles".
```

The Axios Config seems to be ok:

```
date: "{"date":"2017-08-01","titles":[{"title":"title test","url":"xxx/xxx","category":"category test"}]}"
headers:
  Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
  Content-Type: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
```

So, i'm just get stucked here, can't figure out the problem, any idea? hint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your browser’s doing a [CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests), but some internal failure is happening in your server when it receives that request, so the server returns a 500 error response to the request.

And the server doesn’t add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header when it has an internal failure and sends a 500 error response, so you end up seeing that CORS error message.

So the real problem isn’t a CORS error but instead some internal problem in the server—and because of that, to find a solution to this, you need to look at the server logs on the server side and see what message the server is logging about the cause when that 500 error occurs.

> The weird thing is, with CURL the request is succesful:
>
> ```
> curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST \-d '{ "date": "2017-08-15", "titles": [{"title": "title test", "url":"xxx/xxx", "category": "category test"}] }' "xxx/api/v3.6/save_day_titles".
> ```

That’s testing a `POST` request. Your browser never gets around to doing the `POST`; instead it first does a [CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests), but when it receives that `500` error response to that `OPTIONS` request, that’s a preflight failure, so the browser never moves on to doing the `POST`.

So to emulate the browser behavior using `curl`, you first need to send an `OPTIONS` request:

```
curl -X OPTIONS -i -H 'Origin: http://localhost:3000' \
    -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' \
    -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type' \
    xxx/api/v3.6/save_day_titles
```

That should make the server give you back the same 500 error response you see in the browser.

Note that the reason the browser does that [CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) is because your frontend JavaScript code is adding the `Content-Type: application/json` request header, and that’s one of the conditions that triggers browsers to do a preflight.